# Why can't I read a property in BuildBot send from sendchange?

Tags: buildbot

I am trying to send a property to a build configuration through a command line invocation of sendchange.

Here is a snippet of my master.cfg

```
factory = util.BuildFactory()
factory.addStep(
  steps.ShellCommand(
    command=["echo", util.Property('grid', default=2)]))
```

I am invoking the build using this command

```
buildbot sendchange --master my-server:9989 --auth me:mypass --who slineisitanyway --branch=master --property grid:5 a.txt
```

When I check the shell output in the web UI, I see that, indeed, the build did run, it succeeded, and it chose the default of 2, even though I have specified the property 'grid' on the command line.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify `revision`. In this case Buildbot uses property from cache ;) I faced just same issue during testing.